# Java heap space in a looped function

Tags: java, heap-memory

Hi
I have a java application that is processing a number of records from a database. Now after processing about a 160 of these the java runs throws a "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". Due to this I updated the entire function in order to only process 150 records at one go, which works fine when I simply call that function once, however the problem lies in that I have to process about a 10000 records, which means that I have to manually run the same function more then 60 times.

My question is, is there a way I can put this function in a loop and run it for various times without running into the problem. I cant understand why it runs into this problem since the function is self contained and does not make use of any of the data generated by the previous call to the function (as I said, I could manually run the function for 60 or so times and get the desired result).

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1:  Seems like you could just call this function in a loop.  2:  Maybe if you post the code, someone can help you find why you're consuming so much memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you're not closing your `Statement`(s) and/or `ResultSet`(s). These can consume a lot of resources while open. Be sure to close them when you're through with them!

Answer (score 0):

One of the most probable reasons behind these issue are improper handling of open channels/resources. Please make sure that every open handle is closed once its job is done. Open **ResultSets** consume a lot of memory resources. Also, it's not a good practice to be dependent only on JVM for memory management. A carefully written code will result in optimized code to a large degree even without doing so intentionally.

Answer (score -2):

i think that call the function by sevelar times isn't the good way. IMHO you must write an Store Procedure that process all the data. The database are prepared to process a lot of data.

Comment: I would keep the code in the application if it's complex business logic.

Comment: If i don't see the code, i should think that the sp it's the better way to process the data. Architecturaly, the job the database it's for that. But, again, i don't know anything about the code or the logic. :)

Comment: Ok, so, the problem to do the loop it's to know where was the last record that you process, don't?

Comment: No, that won't be a problem. I would write a query that selects all data from the database. All data isn't sent when you execute the query, only the first X records are fetched by the jdbc, and the next X records will be fetched when you move the cursor in the resultset.